# Impute missing values of dummy variables, using R's {caret} package: predicted values in between {0;1}?

Tags: r, categorical-encoding, data-imputation, caret, multiple-imputation

I'm using `{caret}` to impute missing data resulting from non-response to survey questions. All of these variables are defined as numeric, though most are dummies. Using the Bagging approach, I predicted values for those missing cases. The predicted values, however, take values in between {0;1} thus rather providing an approximation than a classification of either 0 or 1. Can I just come up with cut-offs (a posteriori), e.g. "0.9 is basically 1!", or would that be a fundamentally flawed approach?

The issue is, I assume, that caret treats dummies as numeric variables (which it should) and automatically presumes that the variable can take values anywhere in between 0 and 1 on a continuous scale (which is not ideal: e.g. regression analysis after imputation).

Is there a way around this or am I just using the wrong package?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment as my rating is not high enough, so here is my idea as a an answer. I will delete it if it does not help.

I think cutoff is in general a correct solution, as it is used in dedicated libraries when imputing categorical variables. As a practical solution, you could impute your dummy variable as categorical one, using a dedicated library. I am not sure on how the cutoffs work in this solution, but it looks that the default parameters worked just fine on a mtcars dataset.

```
library(missForest)

mtcars_miss <- mtcars
mtcars_miss[c(3,5,11,12,13),"vs"] <- NA
mtcars_miss <- mtcars_miss %>% mutate(vs = as.factor(vs))
mtcars_imp <- missForest(mtcars_miss, xtrue = mtcars)
head(mtcars_imp$ximp)
mtcars_imp$error
```